# Changing the default routing upon validation error (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, routes

I have a uniqueness validation for my line_item model:

```
  validates :course_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :cart_id}
```

If I intentionally create a line_item that fails this validation, rails automatically takes me to /line_items. How can I change this default routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when the validation fails will be determined by the controller create method.  In there you need something along the lines of

```
def create 
     if LineItem.create(params)
         render :action => 'index'
     else
         render :action => 'edit'
    end
end
```